# jdeveloper deployment issue on oracle weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper, oim

I am working on an oracle product Identity Management (IDM).
Initially when I wrote a separate program using Java (JDeveloper) it's worked fine.
Users are created in IDM using that java API.
But when I changed that program with the idea of the Web interface java code is even not able to deploy on
oracle WebLogic server.

### Work Flow of Pages

index.html (this page has 4 options on menu 1. create user 2. delete user 3. disable user 4.enable user)

When a user clicks on option 3. disableuser.html page is called

On disableuser.html there are only 2 controls, a textbox and a button. In the text box the user provides user name whom he
wants to disable and then he will click on submit button. This submit button will call

operations.jsp

this operations.jsp code will call java class (oimuser.java)

Problem:

1. When I try to deploy this code on Oracle WebLogic Server it's unable to be deployed
2. When I changed the machine and used my friend's machine the code is deployed and executed but it's not calling the Java code
   means user is not disable (even environment is not created)

Note: unable to deploy.. with below error code

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaau.rbacx.api.service.RbacxServiceException
```

Answer (score 0):

For case 1) the problem is a missing library containing the mentioned class. You need to deploy the jar containing the class with your application onto the server.

For the second case, I can't tell as you have not given details.